# websphere portal 8.0 sharing session variables using PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE

Tags: websphere-portal

I am using websphere portal 8.0 and using the below api to set the session variable in one faces managed bean..

```
PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
PortletSession session=request.getPortletSession(false);
session.setAttribute("Name", pName,PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

In a different request in a different managed bean I am trying to retrieve the session variable however it returns null. This is a single portlet application.

```
PortletRequest request2 = (PortletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
PortletSession session=request2.getPortletSession(false);
session.getAttribute("Name",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want share variables in JSF , use this methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    return (T) findBean(beanName, context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName, FacesContext context) {
    return (T) context.getApplication()
                      .evaluateExpressionGet(context,
        "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
}
```

It obtain ManageBean instances in your web application. Then, you can access to methods get and set.